# Post content to Facebook Business Page - Timeline from external website?

Tags: facebook, sdk, extranet

Could somebody please provide a detailed step-by-step example on how to do the following?

I need to be able to post new content from our website directly to our Facebook Business Page - Timeline as the owner/administrator or via our Facebook App.

We have an extranet which supports multiple sites/domains, but would like the content from these various sites published automatically to our central Facebook Business page whenever we had content to our own sites.

We have like buttons on our pages, that allows users to like and post to their own walls, but we want to publish to our own business wall.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an RSS-feed containing the posts you would like to share on your Facebook page.
2. Go to your Facebook page and use the top search box to search for 'RSS Graffiti'.
3. Follow the onscreen steps and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried that, logged into Facebook as the administrator of our Business Page, went to https://apps.facebook.com/rssgraffiti, setup permissions to allow app and setup a new Publsih Plan to use our external RSS feed with the target setup as Target (page) Publish on Behalf of (page). I enabled the feed but nothing is appearing, I have tested our feed with the Live Date Preview and our feed appears correctly but just not on our Business page.

Comment: I am using it too. The day I set everythin up, it didn't work. The next day it worked. I think it will only post conent as soon as there is new content to post. Is a post is too old, it won't be posted. Another possible option is that the initial content of the feed won't be posted to prevent large numbers of auto-posts, but the first post to be 'new' in the RSS feed will be picked up by RSS Graffiti/Facebook.

Comment: I've just added a new post, but no joy unfortunately. I will check tomorrow and fingers crossed it will work, again thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the structure of the feed? These feeds I use these feeds for automatisch Facebook posting with success:
http://feeds.feedburner.com/Rechtsdoor and
http://feeds.feedburner.com/fidio

You can easily add your feed to feedburner.com, so the structure is always the same if you are using or planning to use more feed sources.

Comment: There seems to be a tempremental issue, the feed to add a post, then 2 post of the same the next and completly missed the latest post I added yeterday.